# tar 1.27: some gz package is getting extracted but some not

Tags: linux, tar, embedded

I am on tar version 1.27. I have 2 different tar balls of same compression format (*.tar.gz). One is getting extracted but another one is not on same architecture. The error I'm receiving is "Invalid tar magic".

```
file intltool-0.51.0.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Mon Mar  9 01:41:20 2015, max compression, from Unix
```

I tried with `tar -xvf *.tar.gz`

Can somebody please suggest some solution.

Comment: What does the `file` command say when you run it on the two files, and what command do you use to extract the archives? Please [edit] your answer and add this information.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce problem, however I am using tar 1.28.

1. try to explictly add `-z` flag e.g.

   ```
   tar xzf fil1.tar.gz
   ```
2. if both tar are on same directory, do not use star (`*`)

   ```
   tar xzf *.tar.gz
   tar: t2.tar.gz: Not found in archive
   tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
   ```